# How to get json data into AngularJS modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, modal-dialog, ng-dialog

I am trying to display json values on my modal using angularjs. But I am failing to display on modal dialog, but I can see those values on my console or on alert message. Please help me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Created [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5cUV5MwBCAr2eTeis389?p=preview).

**html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <button ng-click="test()">Test</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function TestCtrl($scope, $dialog, $http){
  $scope.test = function(){
     $http.get('test.json')
        .success(function(data) {
           $dialog.dialog({}).open('test.html');
            $scope.items=data;
            console.log(data);
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
 }
 }
```

**test.html:**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h1>Test Modal</h1>
</div>'
<div class="modal-body">
  Test Data:
    <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li>
      {{item.test1}}
      {{item.test2}}
      {{item.test3}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**test.json:**

```
[{
    "test1": "test1value",
    "test2": "10",
    "test3": "100"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you do not have visibility in your modal of that variable.

try this, i've just fixed your plunker:

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function TestCtrl($scope, $dialog, $http){
  $scope.test = function(){
   // $dialog.dialog({}).open('modalContent.html');

    $http.get('test.json')
        .success(function(data) {
           $scope.items=data;
           console.log(data);
           alert(JSON.stringify(data));
           $dialog.dialog({
             templateUrl:  'test.html',
              controller: 'dialogCtrl',
              resolve: { items: function () { return $scope.items; } }
           }).open('test.html');

        });

  }

}

app.controller('dialogCtrl', function ($scope, items) {
  $scope.items= items;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you please edit in my Plnkr, as I am getting errors.

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes it is working fine. Thanks for your help once again !

Comment: I have one query that, I have applied like above in my application, but I can see the json values on my console(in <div class="modal ng-scope>), but modal pop-up is not showing on my page on clicking of button, I am not sure why ? May I know any reason ? I am using angular 1.2.4 !

Answer (score 1):

Issue is your scope variable is not accessible in `test.html`.

I just updated your variable to `rootScope` and its working fine not.

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KB9RgKPlGr4iz9cQOkcx?p=preview)

Note: This is a patch work and not a proper implementation. @Karim's answer, looks more like a proper implementation and should be considered as answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes it is working fine too !  Thanks once again for help !!

Comment: @Karim's answer is also working fine now. You both saved me ! Thanks !

Comment: I guess you should try to understand the real issue(scopeing). rootScope is not bad it's just in your situation, is not appropriate. And I'm glad was able to help you.

Comment: I have one query that, I have applied like above in my application, but I can see the json values on my console(in <div class="modal ng-scope>), but modal pop-up is not showing on my page on clicking of button, I am not sure why ? May I know any reason ?  I am using angular 1.2.4 !

Comment: @Dhana as I have already said, its a scoping issue. You are trying to access something that is defined in other scope. You will either have to define it at a higher scope(my solution) or share scope(Karim's answer)

Comment: it might be the scope visibility as per you actually, but in my application it is resolved with multiple versions of css and angular 1.2 version, I fixed it. Thank you for your suggestion once again !